# What's Wrong WIth My Code involving JFrames

Tags: java, swing, window, jframe

It's Giving me an error saying that "The method setContentPane(Container) in the type JFrame is not applicable for the arguments (GamePanel)"

Here is my Code:

```
package main;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Game {

public static void main(String[] args){

    JFrame window = new JFrame("Dragon Tales");
    window.setContentPane(new GamePanel());
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setResizable(false);
}

}
```

I am following a tutorial exactly and his screen shows no errors at all.

Comment: is your GamePanel inherited from Container?

Answer (score 2):

Your GamePanel class does not extend any Swing GUI component such as Container or one of its children. Probably it should extend JPanel.

i.e.,

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GamePanel extends JPanel {
   // .... etc
}
```

Please don't add the urgent or "help as soon as possible" bit. Yes your question is very important, but it is no more important than anyone else's.

Edit: Mad's link is worth putting in the answer: [The Oracle Swing Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/).

Comment: So how do I fix that?

Comment: @TylerRutherford120 You read a [good tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)

Comment: +1 just for the notice concerning urgent/help asap. Moreover, this kind of question is often ask on SO, a bit more research would have been needed before asking imo.

Comment: Thank You very much! My apologies on the urgency.

Comment: @JeremyD: he's at the point where he probably doesn't know where to look, the deer in the headlights stage. This will improve with time and study.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels fair enough.